# Add more sample points to data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given some data of shape 20x45, where each row is a separate data set, say 20 different sine curves with 45 data points each, how would I go about getting the same data, but with shape 20x100?

In other words, I have some data A of shape 20x45, and some data B of length 20x100, and I would like to have A be of shape 20x100 so I can compare them better.

This is for Python and Numpy/Scipy.

I assume it can be done with splines, so I am looking for a simple example, maybe just 2x10 to 2x20 or something, where each row is just a line, to demonstrate the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want interpolation. Is the question about interpolation methods or about implementations then?

Comment: Let me elaborate in my question, there is some more stuff.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu beat me to it while I was typing this example, but his example just uses linear interpolation, which can be more easily done with numpy.interpolate...  (The difference is only a keyword argument in scipy.interpolate.interp1d, however).

I figured I'd include my example, as it shows using scipy.interpolate.interp1d with a cubic spline...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some random data
y = (np.random.random(10) - 0.5).cumsum()
x = np.arange(y.size)

# Interpolate the data using a cubic spline to "new_length" samples
new_length = 50
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)

# Plot the results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo-')
plt.title('Using 1D Cubic Spline Interpolation')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(new_x, new_y, 'ro-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That does the trick, thank you! Accepted answer because of so much detail and pretty pictures.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,45)
y=np.zeros((2,45))
y[0,:]=sp.sin(x)
y[1,:]=sp.sin(2*x)
f=sp.interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
y2=f(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))
```

If your data is fairly dense, it may not be necessary to use higher order interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not sensitive to precision or you just want a quick overview, you could just fill the unknown data points with averages from neighbouring known data points (in other words, do naive linear interpolation).

Comment: That would be fine. How would I do that for each row of data, ideally without a loop?

Comment: I just looked up scipy docs, and there are some nice interpolation tool available, you should use those. See here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html.  Looks like you just have to call `interpolate.splrep()` to construct a spline representation and then `interpolate.splev()` to evaluate the spline at the points you need. I'm sorry I don't have access to an environment with scipy at the moment and can not provide code. Anyway, all the information is in the examples section of the linked document.